# Java Stored Proceedure CallableStatment Set and Get response

Tags: java, stored-procedures

I have an application that needs two send to variables to a Stored Procedure on a clients MySql Server. I am able to connect to the server and I believe I am able to pass my variables but I am getting a null pointer exception on my result. I have never messed with CallableStatements and I think I have it all set up correctly but I seem to be confused on getting the results. From the documentation, it seems as though I have to register Out Parameters but when I do I get an `Out Of Bounds Array Exception`. Again, I have never used callable statements so excuse me if something looks odd. :)

What I am trying to do is pass the Product ID and Location of an Item and get the Status returned. I think I am close but the IN and OUT and registerOutParameter has me confused. Thanks in advance.

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at cambiumstoredtest.CambiumStoredTest.callProceedure(CambiumStoredTest.java:79)
at cambiumstoredtest.CambiumStoredTest.main(CambiumStoredTest.java:102)
```

Code:

```
CallableStatement statement = conn.prepareCall("{CALL GetData(?, ?)}");

//Pass Item ID
statement.setString(1, "POISCNNR");
//Pass Item Bin
statement.setString(2, "R2S4");

statement.execute();

ResultSet rs = statement.getResultSet();

while (rs.next()) {

    //Get Status of Item
    System.out.println(rs.getString("Status"));
}

rs.close();
```

Comment: I am looking at prepareCall method in docs.oracle.com and I believe this method is looking for a String. I think when you use setString, you are giving it two arguements. thats probably where its complaining.

Comment: Since the stored procedure needs to know the item and bin I need to pass both and in return I should get a result. Should I not use setString? This is what I am looking at right now. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html

Comment: What parameter index is your out parameter? Also, show the exception stack trace with line numbers, and your code with line numbers.

Comment: @TYJacobs, the setString is passing two parameters while prepareCall only expects one. You may need to use a different method that only takes on argument of type String